# layout how to configure

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm having trouble with my Layout. I want a horizontal file, whith two lines each one:

this is kind similar to what I want to get:

[image]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:orientation="horizontal"
  android:gravity="center"

>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:gravity="center">


    <ImageView android:id="@+id/takeBike" 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dip" 
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dip"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dip"
        android:src="@drawable/flecha_1"
        android:background="@null"/>

    <ImageView android:id="@+id/returnBike" 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dip" 
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dip"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dip"
        android:src="@drawable/flecha_2"
        android:background="@null"/>

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:gravity="center">


    <TextView android:id="@+id/takeTime" 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dip" 
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dip"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dip"
    />

    <TextView android:id="@+id/returnTime" 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dip" 
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dip"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dip"
    />

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:gravity="center">


    <TextView android:id="@+id/parkingTake" 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dip" 
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dip"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dip"
    />

    <TextView android:id="@+id/parkingReturn" 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dip" 
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dip"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dip"
    />

</LinearLayout>


<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:gravity="center">


    <TextView android:id="@+id/useTime" 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dip" 
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dip"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dip"
    />

    <TextView android:id="@+id/cost" 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dip" 
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dip"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dip"
    />

</LinearLayout>
```

But what I get:

[image]

where is the mistake?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Android plataform has a specific layout for this situation, [TableLayout](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TableLayout.html).

Your layout using TableLayout:

```
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:stretchColumns="1">

    <TableRow>

        <ImageView android:id="@+id/takeBike" 
               android:layout_width="wrap_content"
               android:layout_height="wrap_content"
               android:layout_marginTop="8dip" 
               android:layout_marginBottom="8dip"
               android:layout_marginLeft="20dip"
               android:src="@drawable/flecha_1"
               android:background="@null"/>

         <TextView android:id="@+id/takeTime" 
               android:layout_width="wrap_content"
               android:layout_height="wrap_content"
               android:layout_marginTop="8dip" 
               android:layout_marginBottom="8dip"
               android:layout_marginLeft="20dip"/>

         <TextView android:id="@+id/parkingTake" 
               android:layout_width="wrap_content"
               android:layout_height="wrap_content"
               android:layout_marginTop="8dip" 
               android:layout_marginBottom="8dip"
               android:layout_marginLeft="20dip"/>

        <TextView android:id="@+id/useTime" 
               android:layout_width="wrap_content"
               android:layout_height="wrap_content"
               android:layout_marginTop="8dip" 
               android:layout_marginBottom="8dip"
               android:layout_marginLeft="20dip"/>

    </TableRow>

    <TableRow>

        <ImageView android:id="@+id/returnBike" 
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dip" 
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dip"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dip"
            android:src="@drawable/flecha_2"
            android:background="@null"/>

        <TextView android:id="@+id/returnTime" 
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dip" 
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dip"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dip"/>

        <TextView android:id="@+id/parkingReturn" 
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dip" 
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dip"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dip"/>

        <TextView android:id="@+id/cost" 
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dip" 
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dip"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dip"/>



    </TableRow>
</TableLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use nested layouts like

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >


    <LinearLayout 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" 
    >


 <LinearLayout 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" 
    android:layout_weight=".25">


  <Button
        android:id="@+id/play_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="left" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/stop_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="right" />

</LinearLayout>

 <LinearLayout 
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" 
    android:layout_weight=".25">


  <TextView
        android:id="@+id/play_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:text="12 02 14:07"
        android:layout_weight=".5"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/stop_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="12 02 14:07" />

</LinearLayout>

 <LinearLayout 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" 
    android:layout_weight=".25">


  <TextView
        android:id="@+id/play_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:text="12 02 14:07"
        android:layout_weight=".5"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/stop_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="12 02 14:07" />

</LinearLayout>
<LinearLayout 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" 
    android:layout_weight=".25">


  <TextView
        android:id="@+id/play_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:text="12 02 14:07"
        android:layout_weight=".5"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/stop_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="12 02 14:07" />

</LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove the tag `android:gravity="center"` in the layout it will be good i think so.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry dude, i was feeling very lazy so did not try to find the issue in your code, but instead wrote the correct one for you. here you go:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="70dp"
    android:background="#1E90FF"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:background="#87CEFA"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:src="@android:drawable/ic_media_previous" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:src="@android:drawable/ic_media_next" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:background="#87CEFA"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:text="Medium Text"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:text="Medium Text"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:background="#87CEFA"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:text="Medium Text"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView4"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:text="Medium Text"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:background="#87CEFA"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView5"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:text="Medium Text"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView6"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:text="Medium Text"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Please see what went wrong with your piece of code. Just for the sake of replying faster, i copy pasted the styling over and over again, you should specify that in styles and use it instead, follow the guidelines, it'll help you in the long run. 
PFB the screen shot from graphical layout:
[image: Screen shot]